# monitor CPU and battery

Tags: android, cpu, battery

I have designed an android application which is perfectly cool and it's working well. but I feel it's using System badly, Because i have written complicated codes.
I was wondering if i can monitor my application. For example see how much RAM, Network, CPU is using and how fast my app is.

by using simple test application such as power tutor .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using API above 19 you can use android profiler.
for more information see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Profiler tool from Android studio choose View > Tool Windows > Profiler or click Profile in the toolbar. If prompted by the Select Deployment Target dialog, select the device on which to profile your app.